# Define elements of list as list

Tags: python

I have a list of variables like:

```
master = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I want to loop over `master` and create `n` lists where n is number of variables.

Also the names of the lists should be by the name of the elements

I tried:

```
for i in master:
    i = list()
    print(i)
```

but here the list doesn't have any name

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a name (that is the same as the element), you probably need a dictionary.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

master = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
d = defaultdict(list)

for elem in master:
  d[elem].append(elem)

print(d["A"])  #  ["A"]
```

You can also do this with dict-comprehension.

```py
d1 = {el: el for el in master}
print(d1["A"])  #  "A"

d2 = {el: [el] for el in master}
print(d2["A"])  #  ["A"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python dictionaries for this . For example :

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
} 
print(thisdict)
```

this will print `{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964}`

Please visit here for more explanations : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)